# How can I plot the covariance matrix of scikit-learn's Gaussian process kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

How can I plot the covariance matrix of a Gaussian process kernel built with scikit-learn?

This is my code

```
X = Buckling_masterset.reshape(-1, 1)
y = E   


X_train, y_train =  Buckling.reshape(-1, 1), E


kernel = 1 * RBF(length_scale=1e1, length_scale_bounds=(1e-5, 1e5))
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=1, n_restarts_optimizer = 10)
gpr.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_mean, y_std = gpr.predict(X, return_std=True)
mean_prediction, std_prediction = gpr.predict(X, return_std=True)
```

I want to plot the covariance matrix that is respective to this kernel. Something in the lines of:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's my first stack exchange answer so I am quite excited.
To plot the final optimized kernel

```
opt_kernel_instance=gpr.kernel_
opt_kern_matrix=opt_kernel_instance(X=X_train)
plt.imshow(opt_kern_matrix, cmap=cm.YlGnBu)
plt.colorbar()
```